# xindy for ancient Egyptian transliteration

Tags: indexing, xindy

I am preliminarily trying to work with creating a couple of indexes with xindy in a XeLaTeX file. One index will be the normal index about names, and I may disturb the list later on. A second list is about transliterated words

As I use ancient Egyptian hieroglyphs transliterated, I need to create an index being ordered in a certain order:

Unicode A722 should be the first letter, then Unicode A357+i as second letter, Unicode A725 as third and so forth (As those signs do not appear in the majority of the normal fonts, I prefer to give the code out of it).

The order is the usual academic order, but it is completely artificial, and not officially supported by any of the languages normally used in XeLaTeX (unless Ancient Egyptian has become a modern language and I did not know about it...).

Is there any information online in order to create a new ordering system for the index, or anyone on the list has any suggestion about a way to proceed?

Comment: You didn’t wrote about that: Did you read the `xindy` documentation?

Comment: @Speravir I have read what comes the LateX Companion, but it could not help that much. I may have to read better what is on the xindy website though

Comment: You want to use xindy, so you must have installed it. Part of the installation is the documentation, too. There must be somewhere a `manual.html`, a `style-tutorial.html` and a `faq.html` – maybe, these are also on the website, I didn’t search there for them, now. As a MiKTeX user I never used xindy, but as far as I see you should search for “define-letter-groups”.

Comment: In addition: Take a look, how the preshipped modules are defined, especially these for languages with non-latin letters.

Comment: Could you please provide more details on sorting you wish to have? I've downloaded [UA720](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/UA720.pdf), [allkeys](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UCA/latest/allkeys.txt), [U13000](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U13000.pdf) from Unicode.org and I've visited http://hieroglyphs.net. Could you be more specific what you need, if this question is still active?

Comment: I have a better idea now of what's going on, there is an old writing, Faulkner index+Manuel de Codage System ([a preview of glyphs](http://www.wepwawet.nl/dmd/fonts.htm)) and a complex Gardiner Classification Order (also used among Unicode charts these days as [U13000](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U13000.pdf)).

Comment: @Malipivo,I have seen your request, I will reply this coming weekend. You have found Faulkner, which is correct. The Manuel you mention still use a pre-Unicode font, so while the signs are correct, some of the letters have to use two different unicode signs to do it. I have not found anything for the new Unicode signs online, so I will do it during this weekend I will post it here.

Comment: @Roberto I did my homework, there are two great fonts in `ttf-ancient-fonts` package in Linux, or, we can download them from http://users.teilar.gr/~g1951d/. I've also found hieroglyphs in color, http://www.qsl.net/5b4az/ (Miscellaneous Software->Egyptian Hieroglyphs), I've checked it there are all hieroglyphs from a Unicode set. I am using mapping to get from letter+number form to a glyph. In transliteration we use British spelling or computer letters. I am not done here, but I have a good idea what migh be needed. :-)

Answer (score 7):

The index processor `xindy` has some predefined languages but not Egypt. So you have to define your own sorting rules. This can be done in your style file by:

```
(sort-rule "à" "a")
(sort-rule "á" "a")
(sort-rule "ã" "a")
(sort-rule "è" "e")
(sort-rule "é" "e")
(sort-rule "ç" "c")
```

Of course this are not the Egypt alphabet ( I don't know this) but it demonstrates the steps. More information about sorting rules are given here:

http://xindy.sourceforge.net/doc/faq-4.html

The predefined language of `xindy` are listed in `texdoc texindy`.